# How can I tell the wireless protocols being used by devices on my network?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, dd-wrt

I have a ASUS router setup using dd-wrt in Mixed mode wireless. Having recently read an article about how even having a/b devices on your network can slow down all connections I am interested in disabling those protocols. How can I tell which devices are using which protocols from the router?

I have a combination of iPads, phones, SONOS, PCs and Macs accessing the network. Going to each device might be an option but one that I would like to avoid. Is there a way from the router to see the protocols in use or a separate program I can run to scan the network?

Answer (score 0):

Any 802.11g device will use 802.11b rates only when the signal is poor. The only way to reliably disable 802.11b is to do it on your access point.

Note that it may disconnect these devices if their signal is very poor.

Anyway. If you have a Linux machine, you can put an interface into monitor mode, use tcpdump/wireshark to capture packets and try to get information about what modulation schemes are actually in use by looking at the radiotap headers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the router, you can setup a monitor port that sends all traffic to a particular port where you can then setup a monitoring software on an end devices such as [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

If you have a wireless device that can install the monitoring software, you should be able to view the traffic as well and determine which protocols are being used.  If you have a separate key for each connection then you wont be able to decrypt the traffic and view it this way.

Each router and firmware will vary from each different kind of device so it would be best to refer to the documentation on the options you have from the router.